# Communicate data between processes in a fork cluster (from R package parallel)

Tags: r, parallel-processing, ipc, multicore

Using a fork cluster as returned by `parallel::makeForkCluster()`, I'm trying to communicate data between processes. What I have so far, is the ability to communicate between the parent and any child processes.

```r
send_to_node <- local({
  assign_gobal <- function(n, v) {
    assign(n, v, envir = .GlobalEnv)
    NULL
  }
  function(dat, node, name) node_call(node, assign_gobal, name, dat)
})

retrieve_from_node <- function(node, name) {
  node_call(node, get, name, envir = .GlobalEnv)
}

node_call <- function(node, fun, ...) {
  serialize(
    list(
      type = "EXEC",
      data = list(fun = fun, args = list(...), return = TRUE, tag = NULL)
    ), node$con, xdr = FALSE
  )
  unserialize(node$con)
}

cl <- parallel::makeForkCluster(nnodes = 2L)

x <- "hello world"
send_to_node(x, cl[[1]], "x")
retrieve_from_node(cl[[1]], "x")

parallel::stopCluster(cl)
```

In analogy to `send_to_node()` from above, I'm trying to implement a function `node_to_node()` which can send an object from one child process to another without going via the master process. What I have so far, however, does not work.

```r
node_to_node <- local({
  send <- function(local_name, node, remote_name) {
    send_to_node(get(local_name, envir = .GlobalEnv), node, remote_name)
  }
  function(source_node, source_name, dest_node, dest_name = source_name) {
    node_call(source_node, send, source_name, dest_node, dest_name)
  }
})

cl <- parallel::makeForkCluster(nnodes = 2L)

x <- "hello world"
send_to_node(x, cl[[1]], "x")

node_to_node(cl[[1]], "x", cl[[2]])
retrieve_from_node(cl[[1]], "x")
retrieve_from_node(cl[[2]], "x")

parallel::stopCluster(cl)
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Just curious if you could explain the application of communication between the worker nodes?

Comment: Some parallel computing intro examples come to mind: matrix multiplication in a systolic array or any problem where space is divided among processes and edge values have to be exchanged, e.g. heat equation, wave equation. I'm after a shuffle operation in a distributed data setting.

Comment: If your matrix can be stored as a matrix, then you should probably use shared memory.

Comment: Looks like `send_to_node` is sending to both nodes. If you try `retrieve_from_node(cl[[2]], "x")` after running `send_to_node(x, cl[[1]], "x")` line, it says "hello world" for me

Comment: @JonnyPhelps are you sure? I cannot reproduce your observation (OS X, R 3.5.1).

Comment: @F.Privé unfortunately, your suggestion is of no help to me. Thanks anyways.

Comment: ah is that mac? I'm running on Linux. Ignore me if its not applicable to you

Comment: @JonnyPhelps are you still sure about your observation? Just checked on Fedora 28, R 3.5.2 and still cannot reproduce.

Comment: You cannot pass SOCKnode objects (e.g. `cl[[1]]`) to another R process.  The reason for this is that they carry non-exportable R connections (e.g. `cl[[1]]$con`) which are unique to the R process where they were created. Unfortunately, R does not complain about this, but it should and could, cf. https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/Wishlist-for-R/issues/81

Comment: In addition to my comment above, although *forked* processes (that share the same address space ["memory"]) would see the same internal connection structure, I believe that it unsafe to append using such shared connections (I don't know how the OS deals with shared connections, but it sounds like magic if it would work)

Comment: @HenrikB Thank you for pointing this out. In hindsight it makes sense, that con objects cannot simply be moved to other processes. So to get where I want to, I'd need to create `socketConnection`s per process, right? Or is there something precluding this?